# ob_get_clean, only works twice

Tags: php, output-buffering, ob-start

Take this simple script:

```
ob_start();
$text = array();

echo 'first text';
$text[] = ob_get_clean();

echo 'second text';
$text[] = ob_get_clean();

echo 'third text';
$text[] = ob_get_clean();

echo 'fourth text';
$text[] = ob_get_clean();

print_r($text);
```

This outputs:

```
third textfourth textArray
(
    [0] => first text
    [1] => second text
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
)
```

But I would expect:

```
Array
(
    [0] => first text
    [1] => second text
    [2] => third text
    [3] => fourth text
)
```

[**PHPFiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/u4z-us5)

Comment: When I try it I only get first text in the array. Seems like ob_get_clean has very inconsistent results

Comment: @StephenTG I see what you mean. PHPFiddle works twice: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/u4z-us5 but http://phpcodepad.com/ only works once

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do this *correctly*  you should be doing `ob_start()` after `ob_get_clean()` because `ob_get_clean()` gets the current buffer contents and delete the current output buffer.

```
<?php
ob_start();
$text = array();

echo 'first text';
$text[] = ob_get_clean();
ob_start();

echo 'second text';
$text[] = ob_get_clean();

ob_start();

echo 'third text';
$text[] = ob_get_clean();

ob_start();

echo 'fourth text';
$text[] = ob_get_clean();

print_r($text);
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `ob_start()` again every time before calling `ob_get_clean()`.

```
ob_start();
$text = array();

echo 'first text';
$text[] = ob_get_clean();

ob_start();
echo 'second text';
$text[] = ob_get_clean();

ob_start();
echo 'third text';
$text[] = ob_get_clean();

ob_start();
echo 'fourth text';
$text[] = ob_get_clean();

print_r($text);
```

Answer (score 4):

[`ob_get_clean`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) turns off output buffering.    It should really only give you the 1st one.  It's showing two because you have a 2nd layer of output buffering active.

Try using:

```
$text[] = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();
```

Answer (score 4):

From php.org:

> ob_get_clean() essentially executes both ob_get_contents() and ob_end_clean().

[ob_get_clean()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)

When ob_end_clean() is called, it turns off buffering. You need to call ob_get_start() again, to turn buffering back on.